# Linkedin Ads/Marketing API doesn't provide Creative(s) data

Tags: linkedin-api, ads, social-media, ads-api

I was working on Linkedin API using (2023 March - 202303) version.
I try to get creative data from API. While my creative was pauesd.
I was using get batch from

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/accounts?ids=List(ids)
```

Example Response

```
{'result': [...], 'errors': [...], 'status': []}
```

There are one of creative was contain in `errors` and have message `CREATIVE_POST_REFERENCE_MISSING` in object.

Then I try to get data from many endpoints with different params e.g. get creative from account_d and campaign_id and also creative_id directly. Still doesn't provide any data it's just return only empty even I try to filter by statuses. The creative(s) is still exist but i still cannot get any data from linked API

Anyone have solution for this?

Also found same issue here
[Linkedin Ads Api Error Creatives - CREATIVE_POST_REFERENCE_MISSING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74001238/linkedin-ads-api-error-creatives-creative-post-reference-missing)
but no one response

ref

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives?view=li-lms-2023-03&tabs=http%2Chttp-update-a-creative#search-for-creatives-1